# ruby could not come after coffeescript in .js.coffee for ajax response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, erb, actionview

I am using Rails 3.1, it seems that I could not use Ruby script after a CoffeeScript statement in my `create_error.js.coffee` view file for the AJAX response.

If I do it like this it will work:

```
<% if @attached_image.errors.any? %>
  alert 'something is wrong'
<% end %>
```

but if it is like the following, with a `<% %>` after the CoffeeScript statement,

```
errors_block = '<div id="errors_block"></div>'
<% if @attached_image.errors.any? %>
  something..
<% end %>
```

I will alway get an exception of `ActionView::Template::Error (Parse error on line 6: Unexpected 'INDENT')` on the `if` line. I've tried several samples, everytime it happens when a ruby `<% %>` comes after a coffeescript statement.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you're running into indentation issues in your post-ERB CoffeeScript. Given this:

```
errors_block = '<div id="errors_block"></div>'
<% if @attached_image.errors.any? %>
  something...
<% end %>
```

The output will look like this when the `if` condition is true:

```
errors_block = '<div id="errors_block"></div>'

  something...
```

and that indentation starts a new block that doesn't make sense in that context; hence the "Unexpected 'INDENT'" error from the CoffeeScript compiler. You can see this in action in [this snippet on coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3apancakes%28%29%0A%0A%20%20eggs%28%29).

CoffeeScript is very sensitive to indentation so mixing ERB and CoffeeScript like that isn't a good idea. You'd be better off putting `@attached_image.errors` into a CoffeeScript variable and then doing the logic in CoffeeScript, something more like this (untested code):

```
errors = <%= @attached_image.errors.to_a.to_json.html_safe %>
errors_block = '<div id="errors_block"></div>'
if errors.length > 0
  something...
```

The JSON version of the errors array should be valid CoffeeScript so `errors` will be a CoffeeScript array. The `to_a` is there in case `errors` returns `nil`, I'm not sure off the top of my head if `errors.nil?` is possible but a little extra paranoia never hurt anyone.

You could also do this:

```
errors_block = '<div id="errors_block"></div>'
<% if @attached_image.errors.any? %>
something..
<% end %>
```

but that's harder to read and you will forget. You're better off using ERB to generate CoffeeScript data and letting CoffeeScript handle the logic.

Comment: Hi mu, I tried to use `error_msgs = <%= @attached_image.errors.to_a.to_json %>` but I get `ActionView::Template::Error (reserved word "var" on line 1)`. Is there anything I've done wrong again?

Comment: Try adding an `html_safe` to keep it from encoding the quotes, please see my update.

Comment: hi mu, if I add html_safe, the : or the [] and {} will be removed by html encode then the string is not a json string any more

Comment: but I am inspired by you and answered my own question.

Comment: @larryzhao: Just adding the `html_safe` should work (at least it works for me).

Comment: is short, it works, I am sorry I was making a mistake. This is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your file should be called:

```
create_error.js.coffee.erb
```

So you could add ruby on it.

Comment: I found this https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/issues/13 yesterday which told me to use js.coffee(without the erb part), and it actually works quite fine with the ruby code part, is only the coffeescript processor won't pass if there's `<% %>` after one of the coffee statement. But it works the other way around, or in between. I will edit the question to make it more clear.